# Spring-webflux / Netty service won't handle any requests

Tags: java, spring, netty, bouncycastle, reactor

Attempting to update a Spring-webflux java service to use BouncyCastle for FIPS compliant cryptography would startup, however every request to the service would end up failing with a stack trace like this:

```
[ctor-http-nio-5] o.b.jsse.provider.ProvTlsServer : Server ignored SNI (no matchers specified) 
[ctor-http-nio-5] o.b.jsse.provider.ProvTlsServer : Server specified new session: 3897681a0667834f4be0c7c579976c84863b65c3cb5b572ab2064488b89069e7 
[ctor-http-nio-5] o.b.jsse.provider.ProvTlsServer : Server (1.2) selected credentials for signature scheme 'ecdsa_secp521r1_sha512(0x603)' (keyType 'ECDHE_ECDSA'), with private key algorithm 'RSA' 
[ctor-http-nio-5] o.b.jsse.provider.ProvTlsServer : Server selected cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 
[ctor-http-nio-5] o.b.jsse.provider.ProvTlsServer : Server raised fatal(2) internal_error(80) alert: Failed to process record
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid algorithm: {sha512(6),ecdsa(3)} at org.bouncycastle.tls.crypto.impl.jcajce.JcaTlsRSASigner.generateRawSignature(JcaTlsRSASigner.java:59) 
~[bctls-fips-1.0.12.2.jar:1.0.12.2] at org.bouncycastle.tls.DefaultTlsCredentialedSigner.generateRawSignature(DefaultTlsCredentialedSigner.java:53) 
~[bctls-fips-1.0.12.2.jar:1.0.12.2] at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsUtils.generateServerKeyExchangeSignature(TlsUtils.java:2587) 
~[bctls-fips-1.0.12.2.jar:1.0.12.2] at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsECDHEKeyExchange.generateServerKeyExchange(TlsECDHEKeyExchange.java:79) 
~[bctls-fips-1.0.12.2.jar:1.0.12.2] at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsServerProtocol.handleHandshakeMessage(TlsServerProtocol.java:1082) 
~[bctls-fips-1.0.12.2.jar:1.0.12.2] at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsProtocol.processHandshakeQueue(TlsProtocol.java:695) 
~[bctls-fips-1.0.12.2.jar:1.0.12.2] at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsProtocol.processRecord(TlsProtocol.java:584) 
~[bctls-fips-1.0.12.2.jar:1.0.12.2] at org.bouncycastle.tls.RecordStream.readFullRecord(RecordStream.java:207) 
~[bctls-fips-1.0.12.2.jar:1.0.12.2] at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsProtocol.safeReadFullRecord(TlsProtocol.java:890) 
~[bctls-fips-1.0.12.2.jar:1.0.12.2] at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsProtocol.offerInput(TlsProtocol.java:1282) 
~[bctls-fips-1.0.12.2.jar:1.0.12.2] at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsProtocol.offerInput(TlsProtocol.java:1250) 
~[bctls-fips-1.0.12.2.jar:1.0.12.2] at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvSSLEngine.unwrap(ProvSSLEngine.java:464) 
~[bctls-fips-1.0.12.2.jar:1.0.12.2] at java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLEngine.unwrap(SSLEngine.java:637) 
~[na:na] at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler$SslEngineType$3.unwrap(SslHandler.java:298) 
~[netty-handler-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final] at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1344) 
~[netty-handler-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final] at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1237) 
~[netty-handler-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final] at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1286) 
~[netty-handler-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final] at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:507) 
~[netty-codec-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final] at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:446) 
~[netty-codec-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final] at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276) 
~[netty-codec-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final] at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) 
~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final] at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) 
~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final] at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) 
~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final] at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) 
~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final] at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) 
~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final] at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) 
~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final] at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) 
~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final] at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) 
~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final] at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719) 
~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final] at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655) 
~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final] at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581) 
~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final] at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) 
~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final] at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986) 
~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final] at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) 
~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final] at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) 
~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar:4.1.66.Final] at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

Answer (score 0):

If a `server.ssl.keyAlias` is configured spring boot will use a KeyManagerFactory wrapper that causes problems like this.  Deleting that configuration item resolved the issue for us.